# Unexpected output of printf("%0x", aFloat) in C

Tags: c, type-conversion, printf

I have a question that puzzles me，code below will print -2.

```
float f = -123.456;
printf("%0x", f);
```

and the compiler issued a warning:

```
format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'float'
```

I'm just wondering how can '-123.456' be interpreted as '-2'

Comment: I would be asking myself how the hex format specifier could output -2!? Clearly the code you posted is not the code that generated that output.

Comment: OHHHH,I'm sorry =, the actual output is 0x20000000.

Comment: This line of code was given to us by our professor, and our task was to figure out why this output was produced. And now, we have found the reason. -123.456 of float type was first implicitly converted to double, which is 64-bits. But "%0x" format will only print the lower 32-bits, and it's 0x20000000.

Comment: If you think that you can explain the output then you did not get the concept of "undefined behaviour". If you still think that you can explain, try making an answer here. (Self-answering is totally appreciated, not a problem. Whatever feedback you get on that answer will only be based on the explanation.)

Comment: In which case correct the question, rather than simply leaving a comment.

Comment: You explanation holds in your particular case but is not robust - for example at https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler it produces a different and unpredictable result every time.  See https://onlinegdb.com/_AfDk_Z8cl for a deterministic implementation that yields the result you get for the reason you have stated. I think that however is the fault of the assignment rather then your reasoning.  You'll probably get the grade with that even if your prof is wrong.  I wonder what your prof is trying to demonstrate with this.  _"warnings **are** errors"_ is perhaps the best take-home here.

Comment: Thank you for being so outspoken in pointing out my mistakes. My code do produce a unpredictable result every single time on the web you provided. I haved run the code on several computers and I haved tried to convert "-123.456" of float type into double and the lowest 32-bits are indeed 0x2000000, these gave me the illusion of finding the answer myself. After this lesson, I think i'll be more carefully with these issues

Answer (score 3):

The warning tells you that the format specifier which you chose, `"%0x"` is only for `unsigned int`, but that in contrast to that what you provide is a something else, a `float`.
The result is meaningless, which is what you observe.
Read up on `printf()` and pick a format specifier which matches `float` and does what you try.

E.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf specifies:

> If any argument ... is not the type expected by the corresponding conversion specifier... the behavior is undefined.

That is the formal phrasing for "meaningless". So much so that even guessing why you get -2 or trying to predict whether the code behaves the same elsewhere or even in the same enviroment is already meaningless; "undefined behaviour" is the term to look up for that scope.

Comment: Yeap, you are right! It's me who misremembered the output of the program. Though i seemly found an explaintion, the code behaviour might depend on machine and environment!! And thx!!